# Vim color is not correct when opened from another script

Tags: colorscheme

I have a custom script written to edit my config files using dmenu. This is the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

OPTIONS="Vim $HOME/.vim/vimrc"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\ni3 $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/i3/config"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\ni3blocks $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/i3blocks/i3blocks.conf"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nRanger $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/ranger/rc.conf"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nKitty $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/kitty/kitty.conf"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nBottom $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/bottom/bottom.toml"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nTmux $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/tmux/tmux.conf"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nBashrc $HOME/.bashrc"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nAliases $HOME/.bash_aliases"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nProfile $HOME/.profile"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nAlacritty $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/alacritty/alacritty.yml"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nBroot $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/broot/conf.hjson"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nMpv $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mpv/mpv.conf"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nZathura $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zathura/zathurarc"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nLf $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/lf/lfrc"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nSxiv $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/sxiv/exec/key-handler"
OPTIONS="$OPTIONS\nStarship $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/starship.toml"

X=$(echo $OPTIONS | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | dmenu -r -i -p "Edit Config:") || exit 1

exec $TERMINAL -e $EDITOR "$(echo $OPTIONS | grep -w "$X" | cut -d' ' -f2)"
```

So when I am opening a config file from this script, my vim opens with that file but the colors are different. This is what it looks like when it is opened from that script.

[image: first]

But it should have looked like this.

[image: second]

what can I do?

For now, I can get back my colors this way. First I open a shell from vim by typing `:sh`. And then when I am in the shell, I type `exit` and I am back to vim with the colors that I expect.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and i3-wm. My vim version is VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 01 2022 09:16:32). I am using [pywal](https://github.com/dylanaraps/wal.vim) as my theme.

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted me to do. But I did this in my script for the last line: ```exec $TERMINAL -e bash -c ". $HOME/.bashrc; $EDITOR "$(echo $OPTIONS | grep -w "$X" | cut -d' ' -f2)""
``` It still didn't work. I didn't get what you said about interactive.

Comment: It didn't work.